# Converting a column in a single cell in R

Tags: r, text, rstudio, text-analysis

I have a dataframe "animal" like the following:

```
 Word            Frequency
  Dog               5        
  Cat               6
```

I want it to look like the following:

```
 Word
 "Dog","Cat"
```

I have used as.vector, as.list but havent been successful. Please help. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `toString`

```
toString(animal$Word)
#[1] "Dog, Cat"
```

Comment: It says I can only accept after 10mins. Will do so .